# Postgres random text in JSONB column

Tags: postgresql, query

Following is the query I'm using to scrub some fields in the JSONB column. I'm trying to radomize the first and last name so would like to use something like `md5(random()::text)` as values.

```
    update people set
    data = to_jsonb(data) || '{"firstName": "random_text", "lastName": "random_text"}'
    where id = 'b3c09005-7afb-4ad6-922d-76078875e59e';
```

I tried replacing `random_text` with `md5(...)` but I get an error

> "DETAIL:  Token "md5" is invalid.".

I also tried using `||` to concat but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the md5 hash as a part of the string so you have to concat it

> ```
> CREATE TABLE people("id" varchar(50), "data" jsonb,"firstName" text, "lastName" text)
> ```

> ```
>     update people set
>     data = to_jsonb(data) || ('{"firstName": "' || MD5('PostgreSQL MD5') || '", "lastName": "' || MD5('PostgreSQL MD5') || '"}')::jsonb
>     where id = 'b3c09005-7afb-4ad6-922d-76078875e59e';
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=43e993be85686df3eafed28e31641934)*

still md5 is old and not very secure, so you should use a more [secure version](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html)